# powershell regex remove digit

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, digit

Using Powershell, I'm trying to remove leading zeros of the numeric part of a string.  Here are a couple of examples and expected results:

AB012 needs to become AB12

ABC010 needs to become ABC10

I've tried the following, but it gets rid of all zeros.  How can I tell it to only remove the leading zeros?  The format of the string will always be letters followed by numbers.  However, the length of the letters may vary.

```
$x = ABC010
$y = $x -replace '[0]'
$y
```

This will display ABC1, and I wish to display ABC10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex searches for a letter followed by any number of 0's and keeps the letter in the replacement pattern but strips the zeros:

```
$x = $x -replace '([a-z])0*', '$1'
```

Answer (score 2):

try this regex with look-behind and look-ahead assertions

```
'(?<=.+)(0)(?=.+)'
```

the problem is if you have string like "0AB0101" that become"0AB11" in this case use:

```
'(?<=\D)(0)(?=.+)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that evaluates the digits as a number:

```
PS> [regex]::replace('ABC010','(\d+)',{iex $args[0]})
ABC10
```

Or using the TrimStart method:

```
PS> [regex]::replace('ABC010','(\d+)',{$args[0].ToString().TrimStart('0')})
ABC10
```